# Best Practices for Transitive Package References in NuGet

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild

I am relatively new to the new .NET project format, and was looking to solicit some opinions on how best to manage a library's dependencies.

Let's say I am writing a library (intended to be shared as a NuGet package) which contains some ASP.NET core functionality.

In my library's csproj file, I can add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Core` and happily use everything I want from it or any of its transitive dependencies.

An alternative approach would be to explicitly add references for each part of AspNet.Core that I use, as I start using types from those packages. For example, to add a package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` the first time I use `HttpContext`.

To me, the latter approach seems like it would be preferable. It provides a more clear description of the actual dependencies of my package, and is not susceptible to breaking in the same way as referencing `Microsoft.AspNet.Core` may be when updating to a version which may remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` from its transitive dependency graph.

If the general consensus is indeed the latter approach described above, is there any way to enforce this behaviour? For example, by failing a build if a project references types in a transitive dependency?

Really interested to hear everyone's thoughts on this!

Answer (score 3):

I'm an experienced C# developer and maintainer of several NuGet packages. Though those packages don't actually have any dependencies.

I agree that the latter approach of only referencing the exact packages used is preferable. This has several advantages:

1. Helps prevents conflicts between assembly versions by reducing the number of packages your package pulls in
2. Minimizes the total added size to projects using your package
3. May enable advanced scenarios for users of your package

I recently had to [file a bug](https://github.com/brendanconnolly/Xunit.Categories/issues/16) due to the third situation. The [xUnit](https://xunit.net/) library provides their assertions in two different packages `xunit.assert` and `xunit.assert.source`. The second enables you to extend the assertion class with custom assertions. I was using the `xunit.categories` package and it references `xunit` which references several packages including `xunit.assert`. So when I tried to switch to using `xunit.assert.source` I got a conflict because they contain the same classes. However, `xunit.categories` doesn't even use the assertion portion of xUnit. It should only reference `xunit.core`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I prefer explicitly referencing packages. However, I can understand the answer may be subjective.

In any case, there is a tool that *helps you find transitive package references*:

https://github.com/spectresystems/snitch

Comment: Good recent article about that: https://gsferreira.com/archive/2022/finding-dotnet-transitive-dependencies-and-tidying-up-your-project/